# Updating the state of an inner component inside a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a `TableContainer`, where a table gets created from `TableItems` which is surrounded by a `MainContainer`, where other elements are.

- MainContainer

  - TableContainer

    - TableItem
    - TableItem
    - TableItem

I now was planning on having a counter for the amount of `TableItems`. Since those get filtered dynamically, I only know in my `TableContainer`, how many got rendered.

To properly display the counter now, I need it in my `MainContainer` though. My approach was to create a state in the outer `MainContainer`, that gets updated by the `TableContainer` by passing a function. The problem I now have is, that my table gets rendered twice, because of the state update of the counter in the `MainContainer`.

I know that I can circumvent this by creating an inner component (`ResultsCounter`) with an extra state, so just this component gets updated when the state changes and not the whole `MainContainer`

```
const ResultsCounter = () => {
    const [renderedItemsCounter, setRenderedItemsCounter] = useState(0)
    return (
        <p>{renderedItemsCounter} Results</p>
    )
}
```

What I don't know is how I can manipulate this state from outside the `ResultsContainer` like for example from the `MainContainer` or from a function I pass into the `TableContainer`

Is it as simple as calling `setRenderedItemsCounter` with a special syntax I wasn't able to find or is there another approach, which is way easier than what I'm trying to do here?

I hope I made clear what the problem ist, if I missed anything critical just tell me :)

Edit:

So in my `TableContainer` I have a filter function that basically does this:

```
const filterEntries = () => {
    let list: []
    props.results.map((result => {
    // Do some filtering and conditional logic
        list.push(result)
}
    setResultsToRender(list)
}
```

Then there's the state that gets set, once the filtering is done

```
const [resultsToRender, setResultsToRender] = useState([])
```

And the return function, that is rendering TableItems based on that state

```
{resultsToRender.map((entry) => {
    return (
        <TableItem
            key={entry.id}
            prop={prop.one}
        />
    )
})}
```

I now know that `resultsToRender.length` is the amount of `TableItems` that get rendered. But I only know this here, in the `TableContainer`.
Where I need to know it, is in the `MainContainer`. I know that I can set the state there by passing a function as prop to the `TableContainer`, but changing the value of a state in the `MainContainer` triggers a rerender of the whole process. It get's rendered twice.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see how the table items get filtered and accessed. Your counter is derived data and as such should not need its own state. Ideally its value is `renderedItems.length` where `renderedItems` is some variable (maybe state, maybe memoised value) which holds an array of the currently visible table items.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the main post and (hopefully understandably) explained the filtering and rendering